# O que significa "Inconsistent modifiers style" no Resharper?

Tags: c#, classes, resharper

Resharper está sugerindo a seguinte modificação no código:

[image: SS]

#### Obs:

1. A `classe` `Pagamento` tem métodos públicos.
2. Por que a sugestão `internal`e não `public`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sua intenção é que a classe seja pública? Então há um erro aí, precisa dizer que ela seja pública explicitamente.

A classe deve ser interna? Ou seja, ela deve ser acessível só dentro do seu próprio *assembly*? Ok, então está certo, mas o Resharper está configurado para obrigar isto ser explícito. O compilador do C# adota a acessibilidade *default* da classe como interna mesmo, e funciona, mas o Resharper acha que você deveria deixar isto explícito para evitar que esta acessibilidade seja adotada por acidente. Justamente o que parece estar acontecendo neste caso.

Ou [desliga isto nas configurações do Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Modifiers_Style.html#preferences), ou deixe explícito que ela é interna.